Gravitational waves from metric perturbation
I have just been introduced to gravitational waves from metric perturbations and I have some questions about gauge symmetry and solutions in a given gauge.
Consider a metric on the form $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$, where $h_{\mu\nu}<<1$.  This will give solutions to Einstein’s field equation which turns out is invariant under $h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu} + 2\partial_{(\mu} \kappa_{\nu)}$, i.e. it exhibits a gauge symmetry. If we then consider the transverse gauge, $\partial_i s^{ij}=0$, $\partial_i w^i=0$, where $s^{ij}$ and $w^i$ are field decompositions of $h_{\mu\nu}$, we arrive at plane wave solutions (with light-like propagation). My question is if I had chosen a different gauge would I necessarily get plane wave solutions?

The reason a gauge is chosen is so that the equations of motion can be simplified and adapted to the problem at hand. Gauge transformations in this context are the same as coordinate transformations. The reason for the gauge freedom is because the exact same physical setup can be described by different coordinate systems. A gauge is chosen not by "removing" the gauge symmetry, but rather by using the freedom we have in $\kappa$ to set certain quantities to zero. The plane wave form of the linearized Einstein field equations
$$\Box^2 \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = -16\pi G T_{\mu\nu},$$
where $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} - h\eta_{\mu\nu}/2$ is the trace-reversed metric perturbation, are obtained by choosing the Lorenz gauge. The actual gravitational waves are contained in the transverse-traceless (TT) part of $h_{ij}$, denoted $h^{\mathrm{TT}}_{ij}$. This is gauge-independent and contains precisely the two propagating degrees of freedom which correspond to the two polarizations of gravitational waves. If other gauges are chosen, the equations of motion will not necessarily be that of a plane wave and coordinate effects, such as the coordinates appearing to wave, may appear. However, physical quantities, such as proper distance, are independent of coordinate choice.
